# How can I make last row bold of a table in jrxml?

Tags: jasper-reports

[image: please check the image for better understanding of problem]

So here I used three text field and every field contain some data.

I want to make the last element in every text field bold, how can achive this?

Comment: You need to pass your jrxml to create a [mcve]

Comment: You need to know the row count before you create the table and pass this to table. Then you can use conditional styles when the variabile REPORT_COUNT == the row count

Answer (score -1):

1. Text Field Properties > Markup > **html**
2. Edit Expression Textfield
   "AMERICA CANADA AUSTRALIA INDIA".replaceAll( "INDIA", "`<b>INDIA</b>`" )

//AMERICA CANADA AUSTRALIA **INDIA**

Comment: sorry but the problem is when i run my sql query in the editor dialog after which i used the textfield of the query to print the data there are four or five fields in my table and what i need is the last element in every textfield to be bold

Comment: thanks for the help but maybe i wont able to convey the problem .i want to know how to bold the last element in a text field it can be a variable value it is not fixed